# Gmap.NET bearing

Tags: c#, gmap.net

I'm exploring GMap.NET for my WindowsForm application. Everything worked well until I started trying to rotate the map (bearing). Zooming with the mouse wheel works strangely when the rotation is nonzero. There is an unexpected shift to another location. Also, markers rendered in the map do not hold their geographic position. When the zoom is changed, the marker is displayed elsewhere.

Perhaps the bearing has been added to the component additionally and it was not completely finished... I've been testing WindowsForm, but it's just the same in the WPF demo application. Tested sources: [1](https://github.com/radioman/greatmaps) and [2](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=greatmaps).

Do you have a similar experience? I am surprised that I have not found anything on this topic anywhere.